# How to fill in the space in the imageView for fitStart ScaleType in constraintLayout?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-constraintlayout, scaletype

I am trying to cover the imageView with the image without hampering the image ratio. I tried various scaleTypes as mentioned in : https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide but each of them has a space left if we don't want to disturb the ratio, I also tried.
How should I keep the ratio and at the same time fill in the imageView?

Comment: Unless the image view has the same aspect ratio as the image, it is impossible to (a) fill the entire image view, (b) not skew the image, and (c) not crop the image. You will have to give up on one of those. You could look into `android:adjustViewBounds` in order to automatically re-size the ImageView.

Comment: I tried to use android:adjustViewBounds, but it just not seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this `android:scaleType="fitXY"` into ImageView Tag...